# Why does my static readonly member get instantiated multiple times?

Tags: c#, static, readonly

I have a `static readonly List<string> ValidatedProperties = new List<string>();` inside of a custom class Foo, and in Foo's constructor I call

```
protected Foo()
{
    foreach(var prop in properties)
    {
        ValidatedProperties.Add(prop.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
    }
}
```

It prints out as expected when I create a new Foo, however, it does this *every* time I create a new Foo.

Is ValidatedProperties being re-written each time I create another Foo object? or is it just displaying each property again because of `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: I'm not the OP but why the downvotes?  The question may be *basic* but it is well formed, specific and contains what the OP has tried.  If I was a beginner and I searched for "static members being instantiated multiple times" this would be a perfectly good resource, which is what I thought the voting system was for.

Comment: What *exactly* did you intend to do here? You are adding `properties` to the same `List<string>` each time you create an instance of `Foo`. So `Foo.ValidatedProperties` will contain a list of all the properties in every instance of `Foo`. Is that what you intended to do? Your `ValidatedProperties` is only instantiated once.

Comment: @EvanL: I didn't downvote, but I disagree on this being a particularly good question. The OP isn't instantiating a static member multiple times and are likely confused about what instantiating actually means here.

Comment: @MattBurland I agree the OP is likely *confused* but the format of the question didn't deserve 2 downvotes in my opinion.  Are we supposed to downvote every time someone is confused and thus ask a question to clarify?  I do however think that a simple search on the meaning of `static` and the meaning of `readonly` would have probably prevented the question.

Comment: @EvanL: Like I said, I didn't downvote, but I didn't upvote either. Perhaps closing is more appropriate? (but I didn't vote for that either)

Comment: @MattBurland I'm intending to fill ValidatedProperties with the properties of Foo once, not once per object. I think I was confused on how the `readonly` keyword affected ValidatedProperties.

Comment: @MattBurland Perhaps, like I said not my issue really, it's just annoying when people make opinionated votes rather than objective votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a feeling that what you are trying to do is have a single list that is shared between all instances of `Foo`, but is populated only once. Perhaps a static constructor is what you want:

```
static Foo()
{
    // note that properties needs to be static too!
    foreach(var prop in properties)
    {
        ValidatedProperties.Add(prop.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
    }
}

public Foo()
{
    // regular constructor for creating an instance of Foo
}
```

Although, unless `properties` is coming from some external source (e.g. a database, webservice, file), it would be a lot easier to just populate `ValidatedProperties` when you declare it:

```
static readonly List<string> ValidatedProperties = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar" }
```

You could even use a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` to prevent anybody adding to it later:

```
static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> ValidatedProperties = 
    new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new string[] {"foo", "bar" });
```

Comment: Thank you! I must have explained myself poorly. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `properties = typeof(Foo).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);` I'm doing this because Foo is (currently) highly volatile and I don't want to have to update ValidatedProperties each time I add or remove a member from my class. Eventually, I'm sure I will use a a `static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string>` as you suggest. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you create an instance of Foo, you add a entries to ValidatedProperties.

Readonly only means the List can not be replaced with another list - it does not mean the content of the list can not change.

Comment: If I _don't_ want new entries to be added, would `const` be more appropriate? Or should I keep it as `readonly` and just make sure `ValidatedProperties == null` before I call my foreach? What would be considered better practice?

Comment: @CharlesW Nothing would work as (a) you would need a readonly LIST and (b) that would throw an error with the current code. I would advice a book about C# basics - you have minunderstandings about static and some other very fundamental things.

Comment: @CharlesW: Maybe what you are looking for here is a static constructor? Do you want a single set of properties for all instances of `Foo`?